# Navigation cannot have 'IsLoaded' set to false because the referenced entity is non-null and is therefore loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to set a navigation property to null:

```
var entity = await _dbContext.Books
    .Include(x => x.Predecessor)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == command.Book.Id, cancellationToken);

if (command.Book.PredecessorId != null)
{
    entity.Predecessor = _dbContext.Books.Find(command.Book.PredecessorId);
}
else
{
    entity.Predecessor = null;
}

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The navigation 'Book.Predecessor' cannot have 'IsLoaded' set to false because the referenced entity is non-null and is therefore loaded.

InternalEntityEntry.SetIsLoaded(INavigationBase navigation, Boolean loaded)
NavigationFixer.NavigationReferenceChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
InternalEntityEntryNotifier.NavigationReferenceChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
ChangeDetector.DetectNavigationChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase)
ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)
ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)
ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
ChangeTracker.TryDetectChanges()
ChangeTracker.Entries()
CoreContext.OnBeforeSaving() Zeile 448
```

The message leaves me puzzled. Any idea what the issue is?

The relevant code from the book entity is:

```
public partial class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        Successors = new List<Book>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Successors { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Predecessor { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OnModelCreating<Book>(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Successors)
            .WithOne(q => q.Predecessor)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this *all* of the actually running code? I ask, because it's not correct (`if (command.Book.PredecessorId)`) which suggests that you removed some parts. AFAIK this exception only occurs by explicitly setting a navigation property's `IsLoaded` property.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah I removed parts of the code to make it shorter. Hm actually I never set IsLoaded explicitly.

Comment: Ideally full [mre] would be great. Also can you please share the `Book` entity?

Comment: Also if you have explicit FK I would just do `entity.PredecessorId = command.Book.PredecessorId` without even loading the Predecessor into memory.

Comment: @GuruStron I added the entity. What do you mean by explicit fk?

Comment: @DarkLeafyGreen I mean explicit property `PredecessorId` which will contain predecessors id in database. Try making `Predecessor` nullable - `public virtual Book? Predecessor { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you need to mark your predec class as nullable, such that it may allow for a null-reference on the navigation, as stated by the error itself:

```
public virtual Book? Predecessor { get; set; }
```

Which also means that the FK should allow null aswell in the db etc etc

Answer (score 0):

For later versions of EF Core with nullable reference types enabled to correctly represent non-required relationship you need to make the property nullable:

```cs
public partial class Book
{
    // ..
    public virtual Book? Predecessor { get; set; }
}
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions):

> By convention, a property whose .NET type can contain null will be configured as optional, whereas properties whose .NET type cannot contain null will be configured as required.
> ...
> C# 8 introduced a new feature called nullable reference types (NRT), which allows reference types to be annotated, indicating whether it is valid for them to contain null or not. This feature is enabled by default in new project templates, but remains disabled in existing projects unless explicitly opted into. Nullable reference types affect EF Core's behavior in the following way:

> - If nullable reference types are disabled, all properties with .NET reference types are configured as optional by convention (for example, string).
> - If nullable reference types are enabled, properties will be configured based on the C# nullability of their .NET type: `string?` will be configured as optional, but `string` will be configured as required.